# Telethon Cannot sign into accounts with two step verfication

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to log into telegram using telethon with a number with two-step verification. I use this code,

```
client = TelegramClient(f'sessions/1', API_ID, API_HASH)
client.connect()
phone = input('phone ; ')
y = client.send_code_request(phone)
x = client.sign_in(phone=phone, password=input('password : '), code=input('code :'))
```

But It still says that the account is two-step protected.
Is there any easier way to do this without this method or... how can I properly use this method?

I want to log into the account fully from the code without typing anything in the terminal (Here I used inputs just for testing. I will connect a GUI later where users can enter the details) so I don't think `client.start()` will work. and I'm a little confused when it comes to passing the parameters to `client.start()` method.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to pass the `phone_code_hash` returned from `client.send_code_request(phone)`.

You could try (see the function call of [sign_in](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.sign_in) with phone_code_hash and [send_code_request](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.send_code_request)):

```
y = client.send_code_request(phone)
client.sign_in(phone=phone, password=input('password : '), code=input('code :'), phone_code_hash=y.phone_code_hash)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I implemented it in my code, using bits from the implementation of `client.start()`.

```py
phone = input("Enter phone: ")
await client.send_code_request(phone, force_sms=False)
value = input("Enter login code: ")
try:
    me = await client.sign_in(phone, code=value)
except telethon.errors.SessionPasswordNeededError:
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    me = await client.sign_in(password=password)
```

Comment: Hi one doubt, can we make and endpoint to get the code from user instead of entering the input from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm:

```
client.start(phone)
```

Watch [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.start) if needed.