# Can't authorize in normal mode

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, python-asyncio, telethon

I have this piece of authorization code which only works in debug mode( it also shows this : Warning: Password input may be echoed. But i don't know how to handle it).

```
with TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash, system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM",) as client:
    phone = input("Enter phone: ")
    phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone).phone_code_hash
    value = input("Enter login code: ")
    password = 'winrarklick'
    client.sign_in(phone, password=password, code=value, phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
```

I tried to use this code from [Telethon Cannot sign into accounts with two step verfication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407031/telethon-cannot-sign-into-accounts-with-two-step-verfication):

```
y = client.send_code_request(phone)
client.sign_in(phone=phone, password=input('password : '), code=input('code :'), phone_code_hash=y.phone_code_hash)
```

But in this case client doesn't have session which i want to save.

Comment: `import getpass` `password = getpass.getpass('password: ')` - but on some consoles/terminals it can still display passoword

Comment: "debug mode" - CPython only has an optimize flag, and that shouldn't affect Telethon. What exactly do you mean?